# Pointing domain to FTP Hosting without changing nameservers

Tags: dns, hosting, nameservers, a-records

I have a domain registered at godaddy [www.example.com]. And i have a free hosting at [Binhoster](http://www.binhoster.com).

I want to point my domain to Binhoster's FTP server where my pages are hosted.

I googled this and I was instructed to change my nameservers of godaddy to Binhoster's nameserver, then add the FTP IP in the A-Record.

But I, without changing the nameservers, Added the A-Record to point to Binhoster's and  added a custom domain at Binhoster's [www.example.com to point to public_html] and its working. I'm currently using my original nameserver. Then why is it instructed to change nameservers everywhere. Is it mandatory ??

Comment: Websites generally aren't hosted via FTP...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to reach out directly to Binhoster to see why they suggest to change your NS. This may be because the IP address could change. If an IP address changes and you control the DNS, you will need to be notified and subsequently update the A record IP, whereas if you pointed your NS the IP may be updated automatically at the host.

Ultimately, as long as you point your A record to the host, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, if you have pointed your A record to their IP address, then your site will work fine. :)